# Как сделать 3 блока одинаковой высоты?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

3 блока. Я уже пробовал использовать как советуют на хабре с display: table, table-cell и т.д, но ни один вариант не подошел.

В принципе он то подходит, но на половину, [пример](http://www.buildinternet.com/live/equalcolumns/method1.html)

но, если например текст мало то высота режется, а мне нужно чтобы она всегда была **height: 100%;** можно ли такое осуществить?

Т.е. должно выполнятся 2 условия, height: 100%; даже если в блоках очень мало текста и они были одинаковой высоты.

Comment: Ширина у блоков фиксированная?

Comment: да, 25% 25% 50%, но они должны быть по центру в блоке с max-width: 1000px;

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619955/Разделение-списка-на-несколько-колонок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

body {
  display: table-row;
}

div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  background: silver;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

input:checked ~ p {
  padding-top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <input type=checkbox id=more-padding><label for=more-padding>Add padding</label>
  <p>And text</p>
</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: не работает, не пополняется блок фоном вниз

Comment: @emtecif, ты не говорил о превышении высоты экрана.

Comment: да, но я это имел в виду) можете поправить код?

Comment: @emtecif, поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container > div {
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .left {
        background-color: #f00;
        width: 25%;
    }

    .center {
        background-color: #0f0;
        width: 25%;
    }

    .right {
        background-color: #00f;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="center">center</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Зачем `table-cell`? 2. Это код не работает без высоты у html и body.

Comment: Вот прямо этот код без каких-либо изменений работает отлично.

Comment: Попробуй превратить его в сниппет.

Comment: Работает, @Qwertiy извиняйте, Дмитрий был первый

Comment: Дмитрий, у вашего кода есть недостаток, если вставить блок в любой их этих 3х, с указанием высоты, остальные блоки скачут вниз, разве что указывать в min-height.

Comment: В общем попробуйте вставить картинку куда нибудь

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю зачем для этого использовать `display: table`. Предлагаю `min-height: 100vh`. vh - viewport height (высота вьюпорта).  [Поддержка: все современные браузеры](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh).

А для разделения на колонки, можно использовать `float: left`, но я бы советовал `display: flex`. Флексбоксы очень мощный и удобный инструмент. На таких задачах как раз можно потренироваться. [Поддержка: все современные браузеры](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

UPD: вместо `min-height: 100vh`, можно просто повесить

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

А флекс растянет контейнер. Поправил код.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}
.col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412 12412 1241212412 12412 12412 12412</div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Удобно, но IE8 не поддерживается. А он идёт дефолтным браузером на чистой Windows 7, которая является на текущий момент наиболее используемой среди форточников.

Comment: @Дмитрий Использование IE8, согласно http://caniuse.com, 1,45%, несмотря на то, что Windows 7 до сих пор остается самой популярной.
Но вы правы, можно отказаться от использования `vh`. Обновил ответ и код.

Comment: Если контент не помещается на высоту экрана, он идет вниз дальше, а блоки чего-то за ним не идут.

Comment: @emtecif вы правы. это легко поправить, использовать `min-height:100%`, вместо `height:100%`. исправил код.

Answer (score 0):

Из практики советую данную проблему  решать сразу на Javascript, задавая всем блокам самый большой вычисленный `height`,  - это поможет избежать проблем с кроссбраузерностью. Т.е. при загрузке компонента с тремя блоками, после догрузки контента этих блоков, если таковая имеет место быть, или в простом случае - сразу, нужно вычислить блок с максимальной высотой и задать её всем блокам как `min-height` или `height`. Процедуру надо повторять, если контент блоков меняется. Если кажется, что это решение громоздко - сравните с огородом, который приходится городить в CSS - ведь код ещё иногда приходится поддерживать...

Comment: Жуть. Уже давно известно, как делать нормально всё на css. Скрипты надо по минимуму использовать, и явно не в этой задаче.

Comment: Не считаю что скрипты надо использовать по минимуму, когда дело касается только отображения контента а не семантики - скрипты работают в большинстве клиентов, а кроссбраузерное решение этой задачи не в вакууме а на реальном проекте с постоянно растущей базой стилей занимает не пропорциональное ей время. Так же как и в случае с `position: fixed` не работающим на мобильных,  вполне допустимо расширять рендеринг браузера удобным способом. Т.к. я использую web-компоненты и кастомные атрибуты, инкапсулировать эту функциональность в удобный контейнер не составляет труда: `<div same-height></div>`

Comment: Косяков в скриптах будет гораздо больше, чем в стилях. Стили браузер пересчитает сам, когда это потребуется, а в скриптовом решении надо за всем следить руками. Размер окна поменялся? Или содержимое блока поменялось? А может ты случайно измерил высоту невидимого элемента и получил 0 или 100 (вот понятия не имею, почему jQuery решил вернуть 100, там реально 300)? Таких ситуаций полно и они лезут изо всех дыр. И не на каком-то старье, которое ты не проверил, и которым пользуется полпроцента посетителей, а везде. А ещё, скрипты нагружают браузер и могут приводить к тому, что сайт будет тормозить.

Comment: да, качество скриптов очень важно, вы правы, не стоит их использовать, если не уверены в их качестве. Я вот jQuery не использую, но вам не буду советовать так делать, потому что у браузеров очень много особенностей. К сожалению, тоже самое касается стилей.